# Scroll animation after a small stop, inverse directions

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, scroll

The title might seem complicated, an example will illustrate it best. I am trying to achieve the scroll effect of this site: http://www.chanel.com/

I've tried many things but can't fathom how they accomplish it. The fact that the window stops for a second before scrolling either up or down baffles me. How do they do it?

Thanks Fuzail for the answer. What you propose I already did. I was talking about the animation. The fact that when you stop the scroll in the middle of the page, it automatically moves up or down, after a one second stop. How?

Answer (score 0):

The Bottom layer is `position:fixed` and the layer which scrolls has been added with a `margin-top:(the Bottom layers Height)`

Check the Fiddle

```css
.bottom {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 80%;
 margin-bottom: -40px;
 z-index: -20;
 background-color: red;
}

.top {
 z-index: 1000;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 margin-top: 80%;
 padding: 200px 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom">

</div>
<div class="top">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
  eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

### Put the Fiddle in full window and try ...

EDIT here is a external [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9e8evvrt/)